# Add custom client-side script that executes when on page

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

Suppose there is an external site that lacks functionality (by external I mean hosted and maintained by someone else), ¿is there any way to add a custom script to it that executes when on the page?

Comment: [This is off-topic (#4)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but search for "userscripts" or greasemonkey.

Comment: You can use GreaseMonkey in Firefox and new Google Chrome have scripts built in.

Comment: Thanks, turn it into an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but this will only happen in you machine. 
For each machine that you want to run the code you will have to setup the plugins and your code.

GreaseMonkey is the most popular, as zzzzzBov commeted.

You can check this tuto to see some screenshots: http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/the-beginner-s-guide-to-greasemonkey-scripting-598247
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/greasemonkey-scripts-firefox